# Can I skip a value of i in a for loop?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C language. I used a nested for loop to check conditions of individual elements in a 2-D array. Basically, I want to check every elements except for those in the 3rd row. Is this correct? Will value i go from 0 to 5 and skip i=2? Or will the loop condition be met when i=0, stops and return true?
Thank you!

I wrote

```
for(i=0; i<6& i!=2;i++){
     for (j=0;i<6;j++){
        if(board[i][j]!='U'){return true;}
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried ?

Comment: Yes, result showed that, the extra i!=2 condition just ends the loop. But how can I write it such that the loop also checks the rest of the values?

Comment: Why don't you use an if statement ?

Comment: also, when you are doing a logical and, use `&&`. A single `&` is a bit wise operation.

Comment: @Ayxan `continue` is almost exclusively bad practice spaghetti and not something that should be taught to beginners. The presence of `continue` in C code is a strong indication of a badly written loop.

Comment: @Lundin you're absolutely right but I reckon it won't be too much of a mess in a code that simple, no?

Comment: @Ayxan Better to stay away from spaghetti keywords entirely. There is never a reason to use `continue` or `goto` in a C program. Yes they can be used in clean, readable, safe ways. But we shouldn't use them still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second clause of the `for` statement is for the loop termination condition, so you can't put anything unrelated there. Use a separate `if` statement inside the loop body:

```
for(i=0; i<6; i++)
{
  if(i != 2)
  {
    /* do stuff */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `continue` to begin next iteration:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
    if(i == 2){
        continue;
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 6; ++j){
        if(board[i][j] != 'U'){
             return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This however will only work on the innermost loop in which the `continue` is contained.

Edit:
This is a working solution.
For discussions over clean code and wether to use `continue` or not rather refer to the [Software Engineering Forum](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Lundin I disagree.  `if(i != 2) { for(...){} }` places the `for` loop at a deeper nesting level, underneath the `if` condition.  That isn't necessary, and can be counterproductive if the code is lengthy, requiring a long run of nested code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle "...can be counterproductive if the code is lengthy, requiring a long run of nested code" Eh? This should have zero impact on the generate machine code, it is just a matter of avoiding spaghetti keywords.

Comment: @Lundin Counterproductive to human understanding.  IMO one `continue` that avoids increasing the nesting level of long bit of code is well worthwhile, especially if that code already has some deeply-nested constructs.  Every level of nesting comes with a comprehension cost.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If it turns that hard to read, you need to write a function instead.

Comment: @Lundin And then to figure out what the loop actually does you need to look at some other place in the code, or in some other file.  All to avoid using `continue`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle You use functions to encapsulate non-trivial parts of code, then give functions meaningful names explaining their purpose. If the code is trivial, such as a single for loop, a function isn't necessary because the code is already easy to read.